# Rendering Panel background in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the background image of a Panel that's on another form. I'm using this as a texture in a DX application. I cannot use "CopyFromScreen" as any other control that is over the top will be included in the captured image. Maybe one approach would be to make a copy of the Panels Background bitmap into memory to share with the other app - don't know how to do this in C#.
Or is there some GDI method?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use objPanel.DrawToBitmap() function it will give the whole this what is on panel.

Comment: Thanks Firoz. That's on the nail. However, as a bit of a newbie with this, how do I marshal this to the exe that renders to the panel? I've found lots of similar code example in C++ but could not find any C# examples. I've done this as separate exe as after some destructive testing, I found that with a separate exe the only out come was that the exe simply stopped rendering. However, with all the code in a custom panel it had an affect on the main app and other panels that where play media.

Comment: You can save this bitmap to tempraroy folder from first exe then intimate second application and then second exe will pick this bitmap from that path.you can see how to send key to another application 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732521/send-key-strokes-to-another-application-c

Comment: Thanks all for your help. In the end I managed to convert and old bit of c++ to C# for the MMF mechanism that I required. Using a file would have been too slow. It works as I need it to. Again, thaks all

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Panel control to see if it has any properties that can return you the background image in bitmap format?.

Comment: This bitmap need to be accessible across process. A separate exe renders DX to the surface of this panel. To create a Pseudo transparency, I've used CopyFromScreen within the DX exe, this is then used as a DX texture. However, if I've accidentally dragged another control over the top, this, or part of it, will get rendered when the exe carries out the capture. Is there a method of getting at the panels bitmap across processes? Or is there a way of getting just the panels bitmap without getting images of anything else on top?