# Add an extension to a normal program

Tags: windows, executable

Hey guys, this question might be a little weird worded but I was looking to see if there was a way to add on to an executable. IE: I use the pandora one desktop application which works perfectly except it doesnt have global hotkeys. The hotkeys only work when the program is the active window. I was thinking of making something that would trick the client into thinking it was the active window when it wasn't so I could use the hotkeys globally.

This question could be generalized to any program (.executable) out there for windows. Is there a way to add on to a "finished" program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is write an application that registers global hotkeys, then `SendMessage`s the other application.

Here is a C# example:

[Send key strokes to another application C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732521/send-key-strokes-to-another-application-c)

or

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx

Comment: but how would I SendMessage the other application? Are there any good tuts out there for this?